# Flash actionscript 3 mouse out

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using the following code to drag an object on the stage. I am using a rectangle to restrict the movement of the the object to the x axis only. I need the mouse to stop dragging when it is outside of the object. The buttonmode turns off but the mouse still drags the object when mouse is moved with mouse button down. Here is the code I am using:

```
var rectangle:Rectangle = new Rectangle(-1400, 600, 4500, 0);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mouseStartDrag);
function mouseStartDrag(motion:MouseEvent):void
{
    strip_mc.startDrag(false, rectangle);
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseStopDrag);
function mouseStopDrag(motion:MouseEvent):void 
{
    strip_mc.stopDrag();
}
strip_mc.buttonMode = true; 

Thanks for any help
```

Answer (score 0):

You could detect whether or not the mouse is inside the rectangle and if it is not you could call `strip_mc.stopDrag();`

First create an empty movieclip and add the rectangle to it.

```
var m:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); 
m.addChild(rectangle);
stage.addChild(m);
```

Then do something like:

```
m.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseStopDrag);
```

or

```
m.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseStopDrag);
```

The event listener would then call the `mouseStopDrag` that already created, which stops the drag.

Comment: I get the following message "1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type flash.geom:Rectangle.

Comment: @Brian Berry You could add the rectangle to an empty movieclip and then reference that. - I updated my answer.